# No view found for id ... for fragment (Android application)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am struggling with following error when I try to invoke fragment layout. Here is the code.

MainActivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void showFragOne(View view){
    FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
    FT.add(R.layout.frag_one, new FragOne());
    FT.commit();
}
```

}

showFragOne is called when button click on ativity_main layout.
frag_one is layout for FragOne Fragment
Fragment Class;

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_one, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

}

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way you are calling `add()` is wrong. The first parameter is the `id` of a `ViewGroup` that is going to host the fragment, not the layout of the fragment itself. For instance

```
FT.add(android.R.id.content, new FragOne());
```

Comment: How to find id of View that is going to Host? By default, expecting fragment to add in after last control in main activity.

Comment: you usually declare it inside the layout that is going to handle the fragments. It could be a FrameLayout for instance

Comment: Can you be more clear please. As you said, for example, I added FrameLayout in activity_main. This FrameLayout itself doesn't have any id. This has to map with one of the views. So how can provide Id of this FrameLayout in FragmentTransaction.add().

Comment: then give it an id, and use it